# How to create backup/snapshot of Unmanaged OS disk in azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, diskmanagement

I have a Virtual Machine which has an associated Unmanaged OS disk with it.

If my OS disk is of managed type it gives me option to take snapshot of the disk. But for unmanaged disk it is not giving me any option to take a snapshot.

Could anyone please tell me, how to take backup of my Unmanaged OS disk?

Why 2 storage account gets created when i have an unmanaged disk associated with my VM?

Answer (score 1):

Unmanaged disks are just using blob storage, so you can create a blob snapshot in the same way you would with any other blob. [This article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/incremental-snapshots) talks about how to do that with disks.

That said, I would recommend moving to Managed Disks if you can.